# Start Typeahead-bootstrap with set value on inputText

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js

I assign the value $nomer on my input text

```
 if(!is_null($nomer)){
    ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
                $(window).load(function(){
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                         document.getElementById('nomeingrediente').value = '<?php echo $nomer; ?>';
                         $('.nomeingrediente').typeahead(); //start typeahead on inpuTextid=nomeingrediente 
                });
   </script>
    <?php

    }
```

This code doesn't work correctly. The function "typeahead" doesn't work with the value that I set, but only if I write in inputext.

With bootstrap-typeahead 2.3